# Can't resize hi-res PSD for web without lots of pixelation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, resize

I have a logo PSD, created in Photoshop (not in AI, not vector) with multiple layers. It is 3000px x 2244px at 300ppi. When I try to resize it to 175 x 57 at 72ppi (or even 300ppi) to put on a website, it pixelates really badly. I do this all the time with other hi-res PSDs but can't figure out what is so different about this file that it would do this.

Any idea what adjustments I need to make to layers, or how I can do this without losing so much quality?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really that important, but as Manly sayed flatten your image.

**1)** If it was 3000x2244 and you want it 175x57 you are totally, totally messing with the proportion. You are terribly squashing it. **Check your dimensions**.

**2)** The 300ppi and 72ppi are totally irrelevant.

> without losing so much quality?

**3)** You are reducing your file almost 20 times, depending on the type of image, of course you are loosing a lot of information and detail.

The only thing I can recomend you is what already being sayed. Flatten your image and resample it using bicubic sharper.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the image first (**Layer > Flatten Image**), then resize.  That might help. Either way, reducing such a large image to that small of a size is likely to lead to quality loss.  This is why logos are designed as vectors.

Answer (score -2):

The answers given are mostly right, but I feel obligated to point a couple things out:

1) *Removed so as to not give out incorrect information. I stand corrected.*

2) I'd argue that logos are designed as vectors moreso to allow small artwork to be enlarged without losing quality, as opposed to the opposite.

Comment: Assuming the pixel size is the same, the PPI *is* irrelevant. 175 x 57 pixels at 72 PPI is *exactly* the same as 175 x 57 pixels at 300 PPI.